# How do I change the password for a login on Azure SQL Database via SSMS

Tags: ssms, azure-sql-database

I'm in SSMS connected to my SQL Database on Azure

I right clicked on the login - no properties choice in the menu

[image]

How can I change the password for a login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in the GUI of SSMS but you can do so with the following T-SQL script:

```
ALTER LOGIN david WITH PASSWORD = 'NewPasswordGoesHere';
```

More examples can be found in the docs for the [`ALTER LOGIN` command for Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&preserve-view=true#b-changing-the-password-of-a-login-1).

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @DavidThielen No problem!